# Fluid Flux field for multible key:value

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I search a flux field for multible key:value entrys that are editable in the backend. For a single line I use a normal input field:

```
<flux:field.input name="Title" label="Title" />
```

But now I would like to be able to add dynamicly values like:

```
Email pp@aa.com
Phone  ++12344556
OtherContat  value
OtherKey  otherValue
```

And then use this in a loop in fluid for the output.

What could I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ViewHelpers [flux:section](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Form/SectionViewHelper.html) and [flux:object](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Form/ObjectViewHelper.html). It looks like this:

```
<flux:form.section name="contacts" label="Contacts">
    <flux:form.object name="contact" label="Contact">
        <flux:field.input name="email" label="Email"/>
        <flux:field.input name="phone" label="Phone"/>
    </flux:form.object>
</flux:form.section>
```

You can then render the data using something like this:

```
<ol>
    <f:for each="{contacts}" as="contactlistelement">
        <li>
            Phone: {contactlistelement.contact.phone}<br />
            Email: {contactlistelement.contact.email}
        </li>
    </f:for>
</ol>
```

There is a limit to this: Inside the `flux:object`, you cannot have a FAL field, like an image.

Comment: it need to be expandable in the backend. I don't know how much contact options there will be. So I need something like `[+] Add another contactoption`

Comment: That's exactly what this does, and also why you need a loop to render it :-)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Yes its exactly what I need thank you (Phone will be the key and Email the value)